# How to derive the gauge transformation of a Lagrangian with auxiliary fields?

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, differential-geometry, gauge-theory, gauge-invariance, variational-calculus

Suppose Lagrangian $L_1(y_1,y_2)$ is a functional of fields $y_1$ and $y_2$, and Lagrangian $L_2(y_1,y_2,z_1,z_2)$ is a functional of the fields $y_1,y_2$ and the auxiliary fields $z_1$ and $z_2$. If we solve the equations of motion of $z_1$ and $z_2$ and plug the solutions into $L_2(y_1,y_2,z_1,z_2)$, we get $L_1(y_1,y_2)$.

$L_1(y_1,y_2)$ is invariant under the gauge transformation $\delta y^i=Y^i$. Is there a method to derive the corresponding gauge transformation of $L_2(y_1,y_2,z_1,z_2)$?

Answer (score 1):

Let us

1. assume that if we integrate out/use the algebraic [Euler-Lagrange (EL) equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Lagrange_equation)$^1$
   $$\frac{\delta S_2}{\delta z}~\approx~0\quad\Leftrightarrow\quad  z~\approx~f(y)\tag{1}$$
   for the auxiliary variables $z$ in the action $S_2[y,z]$ we get the action $$S_1[y]~:=~S_2[y,f(y)],\tag{2}$$ and
2. assume that $$\delta y~=~Y\tag{3}$$ is a gauge symmetry of the $S_1$ action:
   $$0~=~\delta S_1~=~\frac{\delta S_1}{\delta y}Y.\tag{4}$$

OP asks how to find a gauge symmetry for the extended $(y,z)$ system. Clearly, as a leading approximation, we should pick $$\delta z ~\approx~ \delta f(y)~=~\frac{\partial f(y)}{\partial y}\delta y.\tag{5}$$

In the extended $(y,z)$ system, we expect the gauge transformations (3) and (5) and the action $S_2$ to get modified by terms proportional to the EOM (1). Presumably in many cases, an off-shell gauge theory can be obtained via systematic perturbative techniques (a la the Noether technique in Ref. 1).

References:

1. Peter West, *Introduction to Supersymmetry and Supergravity,* 1990, Chap. 7.

$^1$ The $\approx$ symbol means here equal modulo the EOM.

Comment: If $\delta z ~\approx~ \delta f(y) = \delta\,[f_1(y)+ f_2(y)]$ where $f_1(y)$ vanishes on-shell, then is $\delta z ~\approx~ \delta f(y) = \delta f_2(y)$? Or should we still keep $\delta f_1(y)$ in the expression for $\delta z$ and discard terms only if they vanish on-shell in the expression for $[\delta\{f_1(y)+ f_2(y)\}]$ (i.e. if they vanish in the expression obtained after performing the variation of $f(y)$ and not if they vanish on-shell in the expression for $f(y)$ before taking the variation?